# Using Axios put to upload PDF files to S3 bucket via API gateway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, file-upload, axios

I am trying to upload PDF file to S3 Bucket in react js. I have created an API through API gateway to expose put method of S3 objects.

It works fine when I try to upload file with "put" method of fetch whereas axios put uploads the file without body.

Here's my Fetch code:

```js
function handleChange(event) {
    setFile(event.target.files[0])
  }
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    const filename = file.name;
  fetch(`${PutEndPoint}/${filename}`,
  {
    method:'Put',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      },
      body :formData
  
      //JSON.stringify({ title: 'Fetch PUT Request Example' })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Axios code:

```js
function handleChange(event) {
    setFile(event.target.files[0])
  }
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    const filename = file.name;
    console.log(file.name);
    formData.append('file', file);
    console.log(formData)
   
  axios(`${PutEndPoint}/${filename}`,
  {
    method:'Put'
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      },
      formData
    })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

HTML:

```html
  <input type='file' name="file" onChange={handleChange}></input>
    <Button onClick= {handleClick}>
      Upload
  </Button>
```

I have tried:

1. Use content-type as multipart/form-data
2. Remove content-Type from header
3. Add file name as third argument to append

   ```
   formData.append('file', file, file.name);
   ```
4. Change content-type of API to accept multipart/form-data

None of this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs, the syntax has to look like this:

```
// Send a PUT request
axios({
  method: 'put', // the request method to be used when making the request request
  url: '`${PutEndPoint}/${filename}`', // the server URL that will be used for the request,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'}, // custom headers to be sent
  data: formData // --> the data to be sent as the request body
});
```

> // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
> // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'
> // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following
> types:
> // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView,
> URLSearchParams
> // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
> // - Node only: Stream, Buffer

See https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api

Comment: See also this gist: https://gist.github.com/xeniaqian94/559d7016e6cf3a0ce201fc009175a53b

Comment: Thanks for reply.

This also uploads file with empty body.

Comment: I tried using "this.state.selectedFile" instead of file.

it uploads file into s3 bucket as pdf but when I download the uploaded file from S3 bucket, it is a json file.

Comment: I think the download problem should be another (separate) question.. Did my answer help you?